# Select records with two dates with 3 months or less between

Tags: sql, date

How can I make a select Query in SQL where I only want records that has 3 or less months between each other?

Date1 and Date2 column in datetime format: 26-06-2014 00:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DATEDIFF` like

```
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(m,Date2,Date1) <= 3
```

`m` is specifying that the difference must be calculated in months.

Comment: I get the following error: Invalid parameter 1 specified for datediff.

Comment: Try `month` instead of `'m'`.

Comment: Without quotes, sorry about that.